# OleDbDataReader and DataSet

Tags: vb.net, vb6

How do  i change this code to VB.NET?  So i want to use a `DataSet` instead of the `ADODB.Recordset` and an `OleDb.OleDbConnection` instead of `ADODB.Connection`.

```
Set oRs = New ADODB.Recordset
  oRs.Open ("Select * from Login Where Username= '" & txtUsername.Text & "'"),oCn,      adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, _
 adCmdText

If txtPassword.Text <> oRs.Fields("Password") Then
Call MsgBox("Incorrect Password", vbOKOnly, "Login Error")
txtPassword.Text = ""
txtPassword.SetFocus
Exit Sub
Else

strUserName = txtUsername.Text 'May need in the future project
 strName = oRs.Fields("FirstName") & " " & oRs.Fields("LastName")
 frmInstruction.Show
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE  Username= '" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", oCn)

Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If (sdr.Read() = True) Then

strUserName = txtUsername.Text

frmInstruction.Show()

'but am having issue with this line of code: 
strName = oRs.Fields("FirstName") & " " & oRs.Fields("LastName")
```

Comment: Edited your question to quiet down. You should show us what you've tried, simple code conversion questions without own effort are not very welcome at SO.

Answer (score 0):

> 'but am having issue with this line of code:  strName =
>   oRs.Fields("FirstName") & " " & oRs.Fields("LastName")

You could use [`OledbDataReader.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring.aspx) to read the FirstName and LastName fields:

```
Dim firstName = sdr.GetString(sdr.GetOrdinal("FirstName"))
Dim lastName = sdr.GetString(sdr.GetOrdinal("LastName")) 
strName = firstName & " " & lastName
```